# foreach not iterating through array

Tags: php

I'm working on a fairy simple saving class using the below code, whenever I run it, only the first if statement is triggered one time, the data is saved in the logs_all table once and once only. All variables passed to the function fine.

I have spent an hour debugging and have honestly no idea what the problem is, could anyone assist?

```
function saveLog($logtype, $user, $category, $department, $item, $action) {

            $logtype = 'all,buying';
            $a = explode(",",$logtype);

            foreach($a as $value) {

                if($value == 'all') {

                    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO logs_all (user, category, department, item, action, date) VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$department', '$item', '$action', NOW())";
                    $db->query($sql);
                    return $db->insert_id;


                }

                if($value == 'buying') {

                    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO logs_buying (user, category, department, item, action, date) VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$department', '$item', '$action', NOW())";
                    $db->query($sql);
                    return $db->insert_id;


                }

            }

}
```

Comment: please create plunker for it

Comment: From [the awesome PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php): "*If called from within a function, the return statement immediately **ends execution of the current function**, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return $db->insert_id;
```

This is your problem. The `return` statement returns out of the context of the function, or in a global case, the PHP script entirely. This means the `foreach` stops executing along with any other PHP code inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, Must have stared at it for an hour and missed something so rudimentary

Comment: @user1372212 No problem! Please make sure you mark the answer that you feel has best answered your question. You can do so by clicking on the grey checkmark icon below the up/down arrows so that it turns green.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your are using a return. From php.net:

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

Your function is terminating once it hits that return. If you want to return each item, it would be better to save the ids to an array, then return the array after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You are quitting from the function the first time your code reaches `return`.

Here's a simplified version of your code, which makes a use of that your logtype has the same name as the table name in the database:

```
function saveLog($logtype, $user, $category, $department, $item, $action) {
    $logtype = 'all,buying';
    $a = explode(",",$logtype);
    $result = array();

    foreach($a as $value) {
        $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO logs_" . $a . " (user, category, department, item, action, date) VALUES ('$user', '$category', '$department', '$item', '$action', NOW())";
        $db->query($sql);
        $result[] = $db->insert_id;
    }
    return $result;
}
```