# Foreach printing out whole array

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Good morning.

May I get some assistance on what I may be doing wrong here? For whatever reason, the return output is printing the whole array and not iterating through it. The function is suppose to allow user input at the command line syntax, and if nothing is provided, it makes a choice selection of whats available to select from.

Okay, so far the choice selection along with providing the parameter to the function works, in regards to it grabbing the correct array. What its not doing is iterating through the array.

See below:

```
$Group1 = @("1st Group", "2nd Group")
$Group2 = @("3rd Group", "4th Group")

$Resultss = {
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult 'Group1', 'Group1', 'ParameterValue', 'this is Group 1'
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult 'Group2', 'Group2', 'ParameterValue', 'this is Group 2'
    }
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Test-Group -ParameterName GrpSelec -ScriptBlock $Resultss

Function Test-Group{
    param(
        
        [string[]]$GrpSelec)
  if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('GrpSelec')){

$AllGroups = @("Group1", "Group2")

for($i=0; $i -lt $AllGroups.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host "$($i): $($AllGroups[$i])"}

$GrpSelec = Read-Host -Prompt "Select Group(s)" 
$GrpSelec = $GrpSelec -split " "}
$swap = Switch -exact ($GrpSelec){            
            {$_ -eq 0 -or $_ -eq "Group1"}  {"$Group1"}
            {$_ -eq 1 -or $_ -eq "Group2"}  {"$Group2"}
            }
Foreach($Group in $swap){
    "$Group"}      
    }
```

Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-Group -GrpSelec Group1
1st Group 2nd Group

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-Group
0: Group1
1: Group2
Select Group(s): 0
1st Group 2nd Group
```

What the output is suppose to look like:

```
1st Group
2nd Group
```

Hopefully this makes sense to someone smarter than me! I also tried to correlate my script to how this script was answered but, couldn't get it to work:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748452/foreach-not-iterating-through-array)

Comment: Remove the double-quotes `"` from around the variables

Comment: Geez, I didn't even catch that but, I do remember putting them there. Thank you.

Comment: Nice code!  Just a note you may already know, but you can simplify your parameter autocompletion by adding `[ValidateSet("Group1","Group2")]` above/before your $GrpSelec definition if you only expect either of those values to be entered.  Autocompletion comes along with that.

Comment: Hey @Daniel, thanks!(: I actually had the IntelliSense be done through ValidateSet but, it gave me a lot of issues when attempting to do the switch by an integer. It was expecting "Group1" but, the choice selection is done by the number its assigned to in the array. Just decided to do it like that to keep it simple for me. Also tried `enum`, but, I wanted to add spaces which it didn't allow me to. So I decided just to register it properly to the function which gives me an extra feature of adding a description when hovering over the IntelliSense

Comment: Why did you say you could not use validate set for what you are after. Your code works only if your parma is not passed. If you pass the param with nothing it errors out. You can use validate set to get IntelliSense tab-completing while using your argument completer. See my update to your code in the answer, though Mathias R. Jessen already gave you your fix. Also, don't forget about the `parameter help attribute`, that too is an option, though a bit awkward. Also, why not make that `-GrpSelec` mandatory, so, it can't be left off?

Answer (score 0):

***Continuing from my comments.***

Small update to your code to allow for IntelliSense/Tab-Completion on the -GrpSelec parameter and keeping your argument competitor/help message.

```
$Group1 = @("1st Group", "2nd Group")
$Group2 = @("3rd Group", "4th Group")

$Resultss = {
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult 'Group1', 'Group1', 'ParameterValue', 'this is Group 1'
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult 'Group2', 'Group2', 'ParameterValue', 'this is Group 2'
}

Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName Test-Group -ParameterName GrpSelec -ScriptBlock $Resultss

Function Test-Group
{
    param
    (
        [ValidateSet(
                        '0', 
                        '1', 
                        'Group1', 
                        'Group2', 
                        '0: Group1', 
                        '1: Group2' 
                    )]
        [string[]]$GrpSelec
    )

    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('GrpSelec'))
    {

    $AllGroups = @('Group1', 'Group2')

    for($i=0; $i -lt $AllGroups.Count; $i++)
    {Write-Host "$($i): $($AllGroups[$i])"}

    $GrpSelec = Read-Host -Prompt 'Select Group(s)'
    $GrpSelec = $GrpSelec -split ' '
    }

    $swap = Switch -exact ($GrpSelec)
            {            
                {$PSItem -eq 0 -or $PSItem -eq 'Group1' -or $PSItem -eq '0: Group1'}  {$Group1}
                {$PSItem -eq 1 -or $PSItem -eq 'Group2' -or $PSItem -eq '0: Group2'}  {$Group2}
            }

    Foreach($Group in $swap)
    {$Group}
}

Test-Group
# Results
<#
 Test-Group
0: Group1
1: Group2
Select Group(s): 

Select Group(s): 1
3rd Group
4th Group
#>

Test-Group -GrpSelec 0
<#
a space or tab pops IntelliSense for the selection list.

Test-Group -GrpSelec 0
1st Group
2nd Group
#> 

(Get-Command Test-Group).Parameters.Values.Attributes
# Results
<#
Position                        : 0
ParameterSetName                : __AllParameterSets
Mandatory                       : False
ValueFromPipeline               : False
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName : False
ValueFromRemainingArguments     : False
HelpMessage                     : 
HelpMessageBaseName             : 
HelpMessageResourceId           : 
DontShow                        : False
TypeId                          : System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute

IgnoreCase  : True
ValidValues : {0, 1, Group1, Group2, 0: Group1, 1: Group2}
TypeId      : System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute

TransformNullOptionalParameters : True
TypeId                          : System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute
#>
```

> ***Update as per our comment exchange regarding the dynamic completer/validateset examples.***

```
function Test-DynamicArgumentCompleter
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('tdac')]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ArgumentCompleter(
        {
            Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts' -Name |
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($PSitem -like '* *'){"'$PSitem'"}
                else {$PSitem}
            }
        })][string]$FileName
    )

    "Chosen file name: $FileName"
}



function Test-DynamicValidateSet 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('tdvs')]
    Param ()
 
    DynamicParam {

            $ParameterName = 'Path'
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParameterAttribute.Position = 1

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

            $arrSet = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\' -Directory | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
            return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

    begin 
    {$Path = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]}

    process 
    {dir -Path $Path}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I never said I couldn't do it, I said I was just having issues doing it so I decided to keep it simple by not including the numbers in `ValidateSet`. This is just a summarized example that does almost the exact same thing the actual code does. I have about 200+ groups(arrays) I've added so it would be a bit difficult to change what I have to match this. If you have a better suggestion on reading from those, I'd love to hear that. Very time consuming for me otherwise

Comment: No worries, your argument completer and/or validate set can be populated from a file on the system, a directory on the system, RegKey, ADDS, etc. I'll add a pair of samples of dynamic argument completer and dynamic validate set, to maybe give you another approach/set of ideas.